# Sharepoint server application unavailable after .NET 1.1 install on 64-bit 2008R2 server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-services

When trying out a tool on my Windows Server 2008R2 I had to install .NET 1.1. Unfortunately this messed up my IIS install completely.

I managed to recover most websites by running the `aspnet_regiis.exe` tool again (tried both .NET 2 and .NET 4, 64-bit versions) and making sure the Application Pool is set to use the 64-bit framework version and the .NET 2 profile were applicable.

Unfortunately this didn't work for the Sharepoint services I have installed as part of my Team Foundation Server install. I end up getting the following error message:

```
Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently
unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry
your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request
failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.
Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

I have been searching for hours but I did not find a correct solution yet. When I look into the event log there's no error or warning.

When I try to repair the services installation I end up getting an error saying it cannot find the services language pack and cannot complete my request.

Any ideas to solve this issue or where I can get more information without a complete reinstall is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try this way:

1. Start menu -> run -> `inetmgr`
2. On right side, you see ISAPI filters - Click
3. Pick up the Filter name `ASP.NET_4.0.30319.0` as **its path might have an extra `\`** in the path, so unable to load the DLL.

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll

so change it to

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll
```

4. restart IIS - should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

You've entered an unsupported configuration.  I'm sure you know this since you no doubt rebuffed the Program Compatibility Assistant when it told you this upon installing .NET 1.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  With that said, you haven't entered totally uncharted territory.  There are a multitude of issues that you could be experiencing, but I'd start by running through this intrepid soul's [blogpost](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/ivorb/archive/2010/07/15/installing-net-1-1-applications-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) where he details exactly what he came across while doing the same thing.

You may want to check your Handlers in IIS since you've probably got several duplicates due to the fact that .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 both want to do their own thing.

Good luck!

Comment: I came across that post during my initial searches and followed the steps outlined there but that did not solve my issue. As I did not have a .NET 1.1 web application (it was a desktop application I wanted to test) I also uninstalled .NET 1.1 from my machine. As far as I can tell my IIS configuration has no mention of .NET 1.1 anymore. It might also be interested to note that I seem to be able to access the Sharepoint Central Administration pages, but not the dashboards for my TFS projects.